# send DOM through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I create a multiple steps form wizard for creating a multiple record on multiple models on the database and they all work just fine and all the records are inserted in the DB .
my issue is on the edit i don't want to waist my time reload 18 model forms/views once again and load every related record on it's right place.

What i want is to store the whole DOM after all manipulations on add and response with it on edit  .
But i cant send the DOM through ajax post request .

I tried

```
$dom = $("html");
console.log($dom.context);
$data = {DomText : JSON.stringify($dom)};
$.ajax({
    url:"<?=ROOT_URL?>Reservations/domadd/<?php echo $NextId ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data:$data
});
```

And it's not working gives me :

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

and if i dont send it as json

```
$dom = $(document);
console.log($dom);
$data = {DomText : $dom};
$.ajax({
    url:"<?=ROOT_URL?>Reservations/domadd/<?php echo $NextId ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data:$data
});
```

get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

All what i want is to store the DOM object to show it once more on the edit .

Comment: You cannot convert DOM structure to JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the html code as string using `outerHTML`:

```
<html id="html">
    <body>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </body>
</html>

var $html = $('html')[0].outerHTML; // or $('html').prop('outerHTML')
var result = JSON.stringify($html);
alert(result);
```

**Edit**: After having troubles to get values from inputs, you can switch the input type to get desired values:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <input type="text" value="first value (static)" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </body>
</html>


$('input[type="text"]').last()[0].value = 'second value (dynamic)';
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);


$('input').each(function(){
    switch( $(this).attr('type') ){
        case 'text':
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
            break;

        case 'checkbox':
            $(this).prop('checked') ? $(this).attr('checked', 'checked') : $(this).removeAttr('checked', '');
            break;

        //case 'radio'...
    }

});


var $html = $('html').clone();
var result = JSON.stringify($html.html());
alert(result);
```

It is an idea. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/EHSjF/)

Comment: this wont get the inputs values and that are the whole idea

Comment: for now i did a new trick to reset the value attr before sending the html which fixed the input values             $('input , textarea').each(function(index) {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
            });

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DOM as text

```
 var data = $("html").text();
```

and then send it,

but I recommend to use another approach and **NOT** save the whole DOM

Comment: That's really just getting the text content of the page, not the HTML structure.